# Automatic Properties and Collections

Tags: apex

Wondering what is the syntax (if there is any at all) regarding adding elements to a collection defined as an automatic property. Heres the automatic property defined in Class SharingCreator

```
public List <Id> checkAgainst {get; set;}
```

And then i've tried to access it in another class by pulling in the already instatiated specific Object (toShareLater is just a Map of SharingCreator Objects):

```
SharingCreator sOCTwo = toShareLater.get(trustAccount.Id);
```

Then attempting to add elements:

```
sOCTwo.checkAgainst.add(trustAccount.Referred_By__c);
```

However it appears to not add anything to checkAgainst, even when trustAccount.Referred_By__c has a value. What would be the syntax to add elements to collections defined using automatic properties (and I do know i could break it out to a traditional setter and getter, this is a question regarding automatic properties)

Comment: They work just like normal variables. From what I can see here, the syntax is correct. In other words, your problem is elsewhere in your code. Could you [edit] your question to include more code?